# Is there a way for Checking Automatically Elemental Errors?

Tags: java

When we have too many code, and you use a Java class, we should control any input data.

So if per example...

```
People people[];
for(int i=0 ; i<=person_name.length ; i++) {
   people[i].getName(); 
   //This will obviously make a NullPointerException.
}
```

we fix this:

```
People people[] = new People[5];
for(int i=0 ; i<=person_name.length ; i++) {
   people[i] = new People("Dude "+i);
   people[i].getName(); 
   //This will obviously make an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.
}
```

and so we fix it again:

```
People people[] = new People[5];
for(int i=0 ; i<person_name.length ; i++) {
   people[i] = new People("Dude "+i);
   people[i].getName(); 
   //Perfect!
}
```

I know it seems stupid, because it's a normal thing to keep in mind in programming, but well, our thing is to make easier our life, so... where it could be?

Comment: You can correct it. Make a program. Feed it with your common errors. But Oh! You will make many such errors in making that program.

Comment: have a look at findbugs, integrated with e.g. Eclipse, it produces warning for some kind of systematic errors such as the one you talk about.

Comment: That's the dream isn't it. Making tools so that even the less skilled programmers could produce useful code. Eventually making tools that could *produce* useful code. It'd be a lot cheaper than hiring experienced programmers that don't need programs to make sure they don't make elementary mistakes.

Comment: I think the question - albeit definitely weird - is having its reasoning. We may expect that compilers will check for more and more things allowing us making code with less and less mistakes. This is a clear trend from Fortran to Ada, no? Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors can be:

- syntactical errors - these are checked by the compiler
- semantical errors - these can not be checked by the compiler, the compiler does not know what did you try to achieve in your code.

There are two ways to reduce the possibility of semantical errors:

#### Using high-level language constructs

For example, instead of a for-loop use a for-each loop to avoid a possible mistake on variable naming, and start and end indexing:

Consider:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=person_name.length ; i++) {
   people[i].getName(); 
   //This will obviously make a NullPointerException.
}
```

Which is shorter and safer by:

```
for(Person person:persons) {
   person.getName(); 
}
```

There are a lot more of high level trick comes from GoF design patterns. For example, using the builder pattern instead of telescoping constructors can help you avoid of misusing parameters:

```
class Person {
   public Person(String name,String address,String email) {
   ...
   }
}
```

allows you a syntactically correct, but semantically wrong uses of :

```
new Person("John","a@b.com","New York") 

or 

new Person("a@b.com","New York","John")
```

You can program *very* safe by introducing your own domain specific data types with built-in validators, or enforce invariants in a DDD style programming.

These are however go beyond the scope of a simple answer :)

#### Using static code analyzers

A good set of human mistakes are actually easy to detect by tools. These code analyzers check your source code, and add further errors and warnings if something smelly is detected.

PMD, FindBugs, Sonar are tools for checking code quality and enforcing reliable coding standards.

#### No one can stop you

...making bad code :) Java is a 3rd generation language, allowing you quite a low-level access to arrays and data structures. Therefore you can create a Java program which - although it is written in Java - resembles to a C or a Fortran program in coding quality.

Misusing a high level language is actually a common pattern I found in many coders. The reason for that is that they might came from a background of a low level languages (assembly, C), or they have been tought *using* Java instead of *thinking* in Java.

> Besides, the determined Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in
>   any language.
>   ...taken from: http://web.mit.edu/humor/Computers/real.programmers